# How to get element from Json

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my react code

```
class SItemBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      customers:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/api/customers')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(customers => this.setState(
        {customers},
        () => console.log('customers fetched..', customers)
      ));
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="sitem-box-container">
        <div className="sitem-title">
          {(this.state.customers && this.state.customers[0]) && (
            <span> 
              {this.state.customers[1].firstName}
            </span>
          )}
        </div>
      <div className="sitem-buttons">
      <SItemButton/>
      </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I want to get second element from my json which I receive from my backend. 
But it show nothing, how can I fix it?

here is my json

```
[{"id":1,"fisrtName":"test0","lastName":"test00"},
{"id":1,"fisrtName":"test1","lastName":"test11"},
{"id":1,"fisrtName":"test2","lastName":"test22"}]
```

In my case I want only show "test1" in my react

Comment: Why are you checking for the presence of customer with index 0, but follow it up by using customer with index 1? `this.state.customers && this.state.customers[0] && ... this.state.customers[1].firstName ...` I guess you meant to check for index 1, but made a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct on first sight. If you can verify that the api call actually returns the `json` data. Then your state should correctly hold the `customers` value. If that is the case than `this.state.customers[1]` would indeed return the second value in your `.json` which is correct aswel. The only issue I see here is that `firstName` is misspelled in your `json` data.

## 1 more issue:

You should wrap every element in your `render` function in a `React.Fragment` component as you can't render multiple components at once.

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: If you're using React 16.2.0 or above fragments can also be written as [`<>...</>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax).